# Magento 2 : How to get static block as html content on frontpage?

Tags: magento2, static-block, html, block-html

As we know that we're able to render html content up in front as using below  code

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('identifier')->toHtml();
```

but as I require to display as html content.

For eg: `<div>This is static Block </div>`

Like this up in front.

Comment: Do you want to use this in checkout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
$blockHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('identifier')->toHtml();
echo $block->escapeHtml($blockHtml);
```